# Should python "pip" always be up to date on latest version?

Tags: python, pip

Using machine learning models always come with some dependicies like framework or library verison conflicts. And pip verison as getting up, installing some libraries could be suck. What is your pip version? Do you upgrade it always?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite ok if the version is not updated to the latest on every single release.
You will hardly get any problems even if you update the pip every 3 to 4 months.
However I recommend that you should update the pip every month or at least when a major update comes.

For Linux users, If you have a habit of updating your system every month than you should not worry about this explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, there is no dependency management with pip. Most people use conda as a package manager for python because it automatically checks for dependency compatibility. If you use pip as a package manager you have to do all that yourself which is difficult if not impossible unless you have a ton of sys-admin experience. If you are running into dependency issues I strongly recommend downloading anaconda and using conda package manager. It will make your life a lot easier. cheers.

Comment: or alternatively, I recommend getting some sysadmin experience, it will make your life better if you know how to installd/ build dependencies, and keep them up to date, you can then even contribute to upstream to fix their build's or create missing packages for your package manager! It will make your life waiting for other people to fix something a lot easier...